# Android Facebook [4.10.0] How capture when user clicks logout button?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been searching around for the actual logout event button when logging out of facebook.  I saw many people answering with this single line:

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

But I'm unsure on how to use that.

I am looking for the trigger action that actually logs a user out of facebook.  Currently, I am using the `LoginManager` from facebook's Android SDK to log in.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                ProfilePictureView profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.facebook_profile_1);
                facebook_id = user.optString("id");
                facebook_name.setText(user.optString("name"));
                facebook_name.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.optString("id"));
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Login Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Login Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

This works fine when the button is ready for login.  I'm able to do whatever I'd like in the `onCompleted` part of that code.

But since facebook does its own thing with its button and changes the single button from "Log In" to "Log Out", how do I change things when the user logs out.  To be clear, The user **is able to** log out, but I want to change things on the screen when this happens (for example, I want to make the name go away and the picture go away)?

When a user clicks "Log Out", a prompt comes up asking if they're sure they want to log out, then when the user clicks "Yes, I'm sure", I want to control parts of my app at that point.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to handle the logout callback and want to implement some coding when user logout you will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233284/how-to-add-a-logout-callback-for-facebook-sdk-in-android) .