# Delete option to cancel facebook logout

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the Facebook `LoginButton` to identify my users. Once they log in, the button turns into a `logout` button.

Here comes the question. I want to react to a *complete* logout from the user. However, when one clicks the logout button, a confirmation popup comes out, with the options `Confirm` (logout), or `Cancel`. So I can't just assume that clicking the `logout` button means the user logged out.

Is there way I didn't see to remove that confirmation popup and just do the logout?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how to remove confirm popup.
However, I put below condition into onSuccess() to separate between login and logout.

```
    boolean loggedIn = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null;
    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

    if(loggedIn && (profile != null)){
        // Login
        profilePicture.setProfileId(profile.getId());
        userName.setText(profile.getName());
        postPictureButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        // Logout
        profilePicture.setProfileId(null);
        userName.setText(null);
        postPictureButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work as the logout doesn't call the "onSuccess" callback (at least on my version). I had to use the [accessTokenTracker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233284/how-to-add-a-logout-callback-for-facebook-sdk-in-android).

Comment: On my app it call "onSuccess", so there should be the differences. Thank you share your finding.